# Navigation bar with large title shrinks when webview is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, wkwebview

In viewcontroller, I'm loading a webview(WKWebview) with large navigation title enabled. The problem is its showing the large navigation bar and title perfectly before the webview gets loaded once the webview got loaded it shrinks to normal. Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: I too have this problem. It happens inconsistently, sometimes the title will jump to regular and sometimes it will stay. Annoying!

Answer (score 2):

> Swift4, Swift5 :

- The reason of this issue is your navigationBar height is changing when you webView starts loading the page. so using `viewLayoutMarginsDidChange()` we can change navigationBar height.
- `viewLayoutMarginsDidChange()` Called to notify the view controller that the layout margins of its root view changed. This method will get called every time when navigationBar height changes.

Below code worked for me

```
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    private var webView: WKWebView!
    var didChange = false //Set true when we have to update navigationBar height in viewLayoutMarginsDidChange()

    override func viewLayoutMarginsDidChange() {
        if didChange {
            print("Height : - \(self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)")
        // set NavigationBar Height here    
           self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 96.0)
            didChange.toggle() 
            }
        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let appearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    appearance.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset.init(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: -60), for: .default)

    self.navigationItem.title = "WebView"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView


    let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    webView.load(myRequest)

    }


    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Did Start")
      //webView page starts loading
        didChange = true
    }

}
```

Comment: I have to make sure I make `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true` or else `viewLayoutMarginsDidChange()` wouldn't call again

Comment: I have been searching for almost 5 hours to a solution to my particular issue with this. Tried everything else in the book, but this is the only work around I can get to work. Thank you!

Comment: Does not work for me. It seems all good with your solution at first. But then, when you make a two-finger up-gesture very fast, the navigationBar still collapses. Any other solution for making the navigationBar really always stay large ?

Comment: That did not work out for me.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for me, but instead of using

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 96.0)
```

We could use:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit() 

WORKS), but and also order matters 

`navigationItem.title = "Search Tweets" 
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false 
navigationItem.searchController = searchController searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false 

navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit() `

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that works for me

```
override func viewLayoutMarginsDidChange() {
    guard !webView.isLoading else { return }
    navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 96.0)
}
```