# Swift prefersLargeTitles collapsed when WKWebview loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, wkwebview

I create a `NavigationController` with a large title `NavigationBar` with this code.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let appearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
        appearance.setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset.init(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: -60), for: .default)

        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but when my `WKWebView` is loaded, somehow the large title bar collapsed automatically without any `ScrollViewDelegate` code. Please take a look at my gif here to clarify

[image]

Here is my `WKWebView` code.

```
class resultViewController: UIViewController
{
    private var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.scrollView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
    }

}
```

I expect to keep the large title bar visible at first screen, and only collapse when scrolling up event triggered.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The reason of this issue is your navigationBar height is changing when you webView starts loading the page. so using `viewLayoutMarginsDidChange()` we can change navigationBar height.
- `viewLayoutMarginsDidChange()` Called to notify the view controller that the layout margins of its root view changed. This method will get called every time when navigationBar height changes.

Refer This Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57430695/7301439

Comment: Thank you for help, but it doesn't work, I do exactly what you said but no luck

Comment: I've just modified your `print` a bit, an this is what I get: `viewLayoutMarginsDidChange: false - Heigh: Optional(96.0)
didStartProvisionalNavigation: false - Heigh: Optional(96.0)
viewLayoutMarginsDidChange: false - Heigh: Optional(96.0)
didFinish navigation: false - Heigh: Optional(44.0)`

Comment: can i send a demo project if you want ?

Comment: Yes please, it would be nice. Thanks

Comment: download from here https://drive.google.com/open?id=16De_ucDstChcYjVSPqbNWnwG9ZjQjaNB

Comment: I'm trying to fix this and using the example I still have the problem then I have to change

    `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

to

    `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true`